# Does initializing a new object over an old object dipose of the the old object

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net if a new object is initialized over an existing object would this dispose of the old object or just de-reference it, leaving it in memory?

For example:

```
public Class MainClass

dim someObject as someClass

private sub FormLoadEvent()
    'initialize the object the first time
    someObject = new someClass

    'initialize a new copy of the class using the same variable
    someObject = new someClass
End Sub

End Class
```

Wherein 'someClass' is a class that implements iDisposable such as drawing objects like fonts and pens.

Edit: I found [What happens to the old object if you set a variable equal to a new object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707245/what-happens-to-the-old-object-if-you-set-a-variable-equal-to-a-new-object), but it's regarding c++. Would the same apply here?

Comment: When objects are no longer referenced, eventually the garbage collector will dispose of it.  In your example the first instantiation will eventually be disposed of, by the garbage collector, when the second instantiation executes.

Comment: `When objects are no longer referenced, eventually the garbage collector will dispose of it.`, not all true.

Comment: Remember, when you have a reference variable, you have a pointer to an object. When you repoint that variable to a null address or re-assign, it doesn't delete the data at the previous address, nor does it free the memory. See that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285616/disposing-data-table/24286216#24286216)